# Why can't my udf call see a dependency added with SparkContext.addPyFile?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am doing some simple PySpark from a Jupyter console, and I'm running into a problem when I try to call some outside code. My minimal example code has one dependency, `testpackage.zip`. When I call a UserDefinedFunction that uses code in that package, I get an `AttributeError` showing that Spark can't find the function in testpackage.zip.

`testpackage` is a directory containing an empty `__init__.py` and `testmod.py`, which contains

```py
def testfunc(x):
    return float(x)+1.33
```

Minimal example code, I am running this in Jupyter Console one block at a time:

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction as udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

sess = SparkSession.builder.appName("testing").getOrCreate()
sc = sess.sparkContext

DEP_PATH = < path on driver >.testpackage.zip
sc.addPyFile(DEP_PATH)
import testpackage

df = sess.range(0, 12*1000*1000, numPartitions=12)

test_udf = udf(lambda x: testpackage.testmod.testfunc(x), DoubleType())

df = df.withColumn("udf_res", test_udf(df.id))

df.head(5) # error
```

Note that < path on driver > (directory where dependency is located) is in my PYTHONPATH.

Error message reads in part:

> "AttributeError: module 'testpackage' has no attribute 'testmod'".

I'm not sure if the issue is related to the fact that I'm calling `testfunc` in a udf, or if I'm simply not adding the dependency correctly. What is the best way to add a Python dependency programmatically (not using spark-submit)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the module in following way. Can you please try below -

from testpackage.testmod import *

```
test_udf = udf(lambda x: testfunc(x), DoubleType())
```